# Ellipsoid method illustration

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am interested in a Latex drawing corresponding to the following:

[image]

This is a figure describing the idea behind the ellipsoid method, a convex optimization algorithm. It is Figure 8.1 in *Introduction to Linear Optimization* by Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis.

I presume this can be drawn with tikz or some such, but I don't know how to do it so I would appreciate any help.

**Edit:** Thank you for the feedback. The specifications are as follows:

- $\mathbf x_t$ is in the center of $E_t$
- $\mathbf x_{t + 1}$ is in the center of $_E{t + 1}$
- The two lines are parallel
- The right portion of $E_t$ is shaded
- $E_{t + 1}$ is the smallest ellipsoid containing the shaded portion of $E_t$
- The precise nature of $P$ is not important. I just want the picture to look essentially like the one above from the book.

Grazie

Here is my minimum example. The dimensions are not quite right, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}
% \def\myellipse{(5,1) ellipse (4cm and 2cm)}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    % \includegraphics{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt, shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
    % small dot/.style = {minimum size = 1pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 2pt, dot = {#1}},
    % line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45
    ]
        % \tikz \draw \myellipse;
        \draw (0, 0) ellipse (5.5cm and 2cm);
        % \node at ($(2, 0)+(75:2 and 1)$) {$E_t$};
        \node at (-4, 0.75) {$E_t$};
        % \node at (5, 1) {$\mathbf x_t};
        % \node at (5, 1) {\textbullet};
        \node[ fill = black, big dot = {above right: \(\mathbf x_t\)}] () at (0, 0) {};
        \draw (0,0) -- (-2, 4) -- (2, -4) node[right] {$\mathbf a' \mathbf x > \mathbf a' \mathbf x_t$};
        \node[ fill = black, big dot = {above right: \(\mathbf x_{t + 1}\)}] () at (1.5, 0.15) {};
        \draw (1.5, 0.15) -- (0.75, 1.65) -- (2.25, -1.35) node[above right] {$\mathbf a' \mathbf x > b $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are plenty of examples on this site for such diagrams. Please show what you tried so far and explain where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: You haven't explained even important elements of the picture, for example, 1. Are the lines with $x_t$ and $P$ parallel; 2. Does $x_t$ lie in the middle of the interval; 3. Must the darker part of the ellipse be contained in the second ellipse? The potential helpers may not know linear optimization.

Comment: Yes, this can be drawn with TikZ. Please add at least the requirements and how points, lines and ellipses are defined.

Comment: What is the formula finding the smallest ellipse? Let's assume that one of its axis is parallel to the other lines, we only have two points on the ellipse. How do we find the third; the ellipse's radii and its center?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for offering to help. You know, I am starting to think that I should try to do this in a simpler way. Let's say the ellipse E_t passes through (+-3, 0) and (0, +-1). Then let's say the constraint line a'x > b is vertical, so the x_t line through E_t is just a segment of x = 0. Then the new ellipse just has to pass through (0, +-1) and (3, 0).  Then the convex set P can be drawn similarly to the original picture, except the constraint is vertical, and the center point of the new ellipse, x_{t + 1}, is still inside P. Is that easy to make? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that uses

- the libraries

  - `bbox` for a precise bounding box for angled ellipses/arcs,
  - `calc` for coordinate calculation,
  - `intersections` for finding the intersection between the angled line and the normal ellipse and
  - `ext.paths.arcto` for drawing arcs *to* a point

  as well as
- the PGFMath function `x_radius` and `y_radius` for an easier interface to access the values stored in the keys,
- the PGFMath function `rangle(i)` that returns and randomized angle for the corners of a hexagon,
- a `\tikzonline p:a:xy = v;`
  macro that finds a point that lies on the line angled *a* through point *p* with *xy* = *v*,
- some assumptions and
- some other stuff that's hopefully explained in the comments.

This code is parametrized so that you only have to change the values in the options of the TikZ picture (angle, radii of the main ellipse).
However, the angled ellipse's radii are hard-coded since I'm too lazy to do the math – is there even only one solution?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox, calc, intersections, ext.paths.arcto}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{x_radius}{0}{\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{y_radius}{0}{\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}}}
\def\tikzonline#1:#2:#3=#4;{%
  intersection of {#1}--{[shift=({#2}:1)]#1} and
  \if x#3#4,0--#4,1\else0,#4--1,#4\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x radius=4, y radius=2, every label/.append style={inner sep=+.15em},
  declare function={
    ang=110;
    rangle(\x)=\x*60+rand*5;}, % randomized hexagon angles
]
\coordinate (xt) at (.5, 0) % somewhere
  % this finds the points on the line angled 120° through xt
  % that has y = ± 1.5 × y radius
 coordinate (xt-start) at (\tikzonline xt:ang:y=+1.5*y_radius;)
 coordinate (xt-end)   at (\tikzonline xt:ang:y=-1.5*y_radius;)
;

% Let's draw the normal ellipse with the given radii
% the path picture is used to fill everything right of the angled line
% but inside the ellipse.
\draw (xt) circle[] [name path=Et][
 path picture={
   \fill[lightgray] (xt-start) -| (path picture bounding box.east)
                               |- (xt-end) -- cycle;}];
% draw the angled line
\draw (xt-start) -- (xt-end)
  node[right] {$\mathbf{a'x} > \mathbf{a'x}_t$}
  [name path=xt];

% find the intersection points between ellipse and angled line
\tikzset{name intersections={of=Et and xt}}
% the intersections are known but the ellipse through those points is not
% guesstimating some radii
% use a precise bezier bounding box for the angled ellipse
\draw[rotate=ang, x radius=3, y radius=2.34, bezier bounding box]
  (intersection-1) arc to[small] coordinate (xt+1-) (intersection-2)
                   arc to[large] coordinate (xt+1+) cycle;

% since the ellipse is angled like the line
% the center of the ellipse is the center
% between the halfway points on those arcs
\draw 
 coordinate (xt+1) at ($(xt+1-)!.5!(xt+1+)$)
% let's place the other line halfway between the centers
 coordinate (2nd) at ($(xt)!.5!(xt+1)$)
    (\tikzonline 2nd:ang:y=+.7*y_radius;) coordinate (2nd-start)
 -- (\tikzonline 2nd:ang:y=-.7*y_radius;) coordinate (2nd-end)
 node [above right] {$\mathbf{a'x} > b$}
 % do this in an angled canvas for easier math
 [rotate=ang]
 % these intersections are randomized corners of the hexagon
 % but placed on the parallel line
    (intersection of 2nd-start--2nd-end and xt+1--{[shift=(rangle 1:1)]xt+1})
 -- plot[samples at = {0, 5, 4, 3}] ([shift={(rangle \x:1)}]xt+1)
 -- (intersection of 2nd-start--2nd-end and xt+1--{[shift=(rangle 2:1)]xt+1})
;

% label and draw the points
\node foreach \c/\l in {xt/"$\mathbf x_t$" above right,
                        xt+1/"$\mathbf x_{t+1}$" below}
  [shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2.5pt,
   style/.expand once=\l] at (\c) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: this is incredible work. thank you very much. it doesn't run on overleaf for some weird reason, but the picture is fantastic. Thanks again.